# MSSQL CAST in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql-server

In a web app I've written there was a problem with char codes, I was running a UTF-8 html page reading from a mssql with a collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS, basically a massive pain to print proper special chars. I've dealt with it using a `CAST` in my `SELECT` to `varbinary`. Something on the lines of:

```
 SELECT CAST(table_name.column_name AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS column_name FROM table_name
```

Since this was not enough I had to force the html page to ISO-8859-1 like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Now I have another problem, how to make a `WHERE` clause where the user inputs the string?

I've thought about doing a cast on the `WHERE` clause, however I didn't have a lot of luck in my several tries. I did something like:

```
$query = $query." WHERE CAST(table_name.colunm_name AS VARBINARY(MAX)) LIKE '%".(binary)$string."%'";
```

And

```
$query = $query." WHERE CAST(table_name.colunm_name AS VARBINARY(MAX)) LIKE '%".$string."%'";
```

Both this tries I was unlucky with. Even if i typed without special chars, the query wouldn't return any results.

Can this be done this way? Or do you think of another way?

Also I've checked the charset of the strings I want to compare with and to and I got `ASCII` when no special chars envolved and `UTF-8` when chars are involved.

Answer (score 0):

To use the CAST function,  I use a sub query:

Select * from (Select Cast(table_name.column_name as Varbinary(max)) [Name]) As NameList
Where Name %Param1%;